# How to pull object from array with array of matching key-value pair

Tags: mongodb

i have the below array structure in MongoDB

```
{
  "_id": "5dff75968102f11e20ae888e",
  "docID": "Employees",
  "data": [
    {
      "Employee No": "234768241",
      "Employee Name": "Gretchen Goodpaster"
    },
    {
      "Employee No": "234768242",
      "Employee Name": "Bettie Brett"
    },
    {
      "Employee No": "234768243",
      "Employee Name": "Joette Dorazio"
    },
    {
      "Employee No": "234768244",
      "Employee Name": "Freeman Edison"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would want pass the array of Employee No's as below and pull the objects with matching Employee No's.

```
let data = [{Employee No": "234768241"}, {"Employee No": "234768242"}]
```

What i have tried so far

```
collection.updateOne(
    { docID: "Employees" },
    {
        $pull: {
            "data": { $in: data }
        }
    }
);
```

But this doesn't remove the object from the array, but if i pass the object array with both Employee No & Employee Name then it is getting deleted. I'm looking for the solution where only one Employee No array can be used to pull the objects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all  defined field which apply condition in array.

```
db.demo.update(
    { docID: "Employees" },
    { $pull: { data: { "Employee No":{$in:["234768242","234768243"]} } } },
    { multi: true }
);
```

Comment: Please tell your params condition ?

Comment: I'm not sure which param you mean, but my only concern with your solution is string "Employee No" being hardcoded, i would be fine if that can be replace with some variable like $keyColumn.

Comment: Can you share your one sample request data ??

Comment: Its there in the question -> let data = [{Employee No": "234768241"}, {"Employee No": "234768242"}]

Comment: Can you share Schema ?

Comment: Collection name is Employees, there is only one document in the collection, i.e present in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204980/discussion-between-ram-kumar-and-mahesh-bhatnagar).